# Agricultural Access Roads

Tags: gravel, gates

I moved to an area with lots of agriculture and ranching.  There are fields of crops all over this county and many of those fields have access roads going to and around them. Virtually none of those roads have signs and even fewer have gates.

Is there an established etiquette for where the public is permitted to bike in these areas?  Identifying and contacting all the landowners along a bike route would be a nightmare.  The one time I encountered a farmer who wasn't in a tractor she seemed happy to see me and talked my ear off.  They usually at least wave.

Then I encountered a ranch hand in an area where fields meet pastures and he was an asshole despite not having signs and his "gate" being a coil of barbed wire stashed out of sight.  He definitely did not want me on his land, I don't know why he couldn't spend $1 on a sign.  Fortunately I looked him up and he doesn't own much.  It's just shitty to have to detour around him in the middle of a route.

So is there a way to know where it's ok to bike other than trial and error or becoming a detective so I can track down and ask permission from every land owner?

Comment: To begin to answer one would need to know where you are in the world.

Comment: I wonder if this question would be better suited to the law stack exchange instead.

Comment: Sounds to me like you've got a route planned out, so why not just get permission form land owners.  Think I quite often do is (and far from exact science), have a look at the Strava heatmap, tells you where others are riding (if enough uptake in area) and you can almost assume if others are riding there, you can too.

Comment: I'm in a very rural area of northeastern Colorado.  Strava was a good idea but I don't subscribe (no heatmaps) and there are only 7 segments in my area, all on pavement.

Comment: There are roads all over but the best rides tend to be along one of the three canals that cross the county. That's where I mainly want to ride but to run the whole length of the county is countless parcels/landowners.

Comment: Yes, some farmers don't want bicycles on their land - oh well. If you encounter an angry groundskeeper again, just be friendly, say "sorry, I didn't know", don't get into any argument but just turn around and leave. Else I'd just carry on using such roads, but this is not legal advice.

Comment: Komoot has Open Street Map based mapping. It shows rideable routes and will show “not allowed” markers if previous contributors have added them. You can add the markup too as you learn about your local area.

Comment: komoot looks awesome but unfotunately doesn't show any results for this area, even with a 100 mile search radius.